# Determining number of outcomes when a coin is tossed, a die is rolled, and then a card is drawn from a standard deck with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

You toss a coin, then roll a dice, and then draw a card from a 52-card deck. How
many different outcomes are there? How many outcomes are there in which the
dice lands on a 3? How many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on an
odd number? How many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on an odd
number and the card is a King?

For the total number of outcomes, we have $2×6×52$ by the multiplication principle (each action is independent of the other) because we have 2 possible outcomes for the coin, 6 possible outcomes for the dice and 52 possible outcomes for the deck of cards.

Here is where I get confused. On one hand, if I assume that I have to repeat all three actions one after the other to count the outcomes in which the dice lands on a three, my answer is $2×1×52$.

On the other hand, if I assume I only take the action of rolling the dice by itself without performing the other two actions,y answer is $1$.

A similar thinking is involved in the other answers.

For the outcomes in which the dice lands on an
odd number, my answer is $2×3×52$ for the actions done one after another or $3$ for the action of only throwing the die.

For the outcomes in which the dice lands on an
odd number and the card is a King, my answer is $2×3×4$ for the three actions done one after the other or  $3×4$ for the action of throwing the dice and drawing a card.

Which answer is correct for each question?

Comment: "On the other hand, if I assume I only take the action of rolling the dice by itself without performing the other two actions,y answer is 1" — well there's your problem right there. Why are you making that assumption when the question clearly states that you DO perform all three actions? Not to mention that it should be intuitively obvious that, with $2\cdot 6 \cdot 52$ unique outcomes, there ought to be WAY more than just 1 of them in which the die shows a 3. The result you obtained by _not_ making that assumption is, in fact, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of understanding the question. Let's see:

> You toss a coin, then roll a dice, and then draw a card from a 52-card deck.
>
> 1. How many different outcomes are there?
> 2. How many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on a 3?
> 3. How many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on an odd number?
> 4. How many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on an odd number and the card is a King?

I believe the maker of the question means this:

You toss a coin, then roll a dice, and then draw a card from a 52-card deck.

1. How many different outcomes are there?
2. **Out of the outcomes in the first question**, how many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on a 3?
3. **Out of the outcomes in the first question**, how many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on an odd number?
4. **Out of the outcomes in the first question**, how many outcomes are there in which the dice lands on an odd number and the card is a King?

Therefore the answers are respectively $2\times 6\times 52$, $2\times 1\times 52$, $2\times 3\times 52$, and $2\times 3\times 4$, because **in each question you do all three actions**.